# Can someone create a prepare for segue to move the map to another View Controller in this code?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I've been trying to code in swift a prepare for segue or to push view controller in order to move a map with a pin i have in a View Controller to another View Controller but in a smaller version. If someone can give an example on how to do it with this code, you would be very helpful.

I've been trying to do this in this function, so that when the user clears the pin title it goes to the other view controller with that same map:

```
 if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        print("Disclosure Pressed!")
    }
```

Here's the complete code for this View Controller.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

protocol HandleMapSearch {
func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil
var selectedPin:MKPlacemark? = nil


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestLocation()

    //
    let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
    resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
    //
    let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
    navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
    //
    resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
    //
    locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView
    //
    locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
    //
    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Action:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}

extension ViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("error:: \(error)")
}
}

extension ViewController: HandleMapSearch {
func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark){
    // cache the pin
    selectedPin = placemark
    // clear existing pins
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
    annotation.title = placemark.name
    if let city = placemark.locality,
        let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
        annotation.subtitle = "\(city) \(state)"
    }
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}
}
extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    pinView?.canShowCallout = true
    pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
    return pinView
}
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        print("Disclosure Pressed!")
    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. Don't do that.

Trying to move views between view controllers is almost certainly the wrong way to do things.

It absolutely will not work to move a view (including a map view) from one view controller to another in `prepareForSegue`. The destination view controller's views haven't been loaded when `prepareForSegue` is called.

Instead, if you want to show a map in both your current view controller and the one to which you are segueing, you should define a map view in both view controllers, sized the way you want them in both places. You can then use prepareForSegue to tell the destination view controller the map region to display in it's map view. (Don't try to manipulate the destination view controller's map view from prepareForSegue. It won't work, and it's bad design even if you could make it work.)

Add a property `mapRegion` of type `MKCoordinateRegion` to the destination view controller. In the source view controller's `prepareForSegue`, get the map region of the current map and set the destination view controller's `mapRegion` property using that value.

Then, in the destination view controller's `viewWillAppear:animated` method, take the `mapRegion` property and used it to set the map view's region.

### EDIT:

You also mentioned a pin. If you want the same pin to appear in both maps you should be able to fetch the MKAnnotation from the source view controller's map and pass it to the destination view controller, much like I described for setting the map region.

Comment: If I shouldn't try to manipulate the destination view controller's map view from prepareForSegue how can I make it work then?

Comment: I told you in my answer. To repeat: Add properties to your destination view controller that let you specify a map region and/or a an annotation object. Then in your destination view controller's viewWillAppear method, set those values on the map.

Comment: You should treat this as a rule in iOS/Mac OS development. Don't touch another view controller's views. Ever. Consider them the private property of the owning view controller.

Comment: Oh, yes. I'm going to try that and see if it works. Thank you for the answer and the advice!